# Compute Random Forest with a leave one ID out cross validation

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

I have a dataframe `df`

```
 dput(df)
    structure(list(ID = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9), Y = c(2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 
2269.1387550775, 2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 
2359.51909126411, 2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 
567.150629704352, 781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 1107.37695799186, 
1160.80594193377, 1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 685.154353165934, 
574.088067465695, 650.30821636616, 494.185166497016, 436.312162090908
), P = c(1750.51986303926, 1614.11541634798, 951.847023338079, 
1119.3682884872, 1112.38984390156, 1270.65773075982, 1234.72262170166, 
1338.46096616983, 1198.95775346458, 1136.69287367165, 1265.46480803983, 
1364.70149818063, 1112.37006707489, 1346.49240261316, 1740.56677791104, 
1410.99217295647, 1693.18871380948, 275.447173420805, 396.449789014179, 
251.609239829704, 215.432550271042, 55.5336257666349), A = c(49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 163, 
164, 165, 153, 154), TA = c(9.10006221322572, 7.65505467142961, 
8.21480062559674, 8.09251754304318, 8.466220758789, 8.48094407814006, 
8.77304120569444, 8.31727518543397, 8.14410265791868, 8.80921738865237, 
9.04091478341757, 9.66233618146246, 8.77015716015164, 9.46037931956657, 
9.59702379240667, 10.1739258740118, 9.39524442215692, -0.00568604734662462, 
-2.12940164413048, -0.428603434930109, 1.52337963973006, -1.04714984064565
), TS = c(9.6499861763085, 7.00622420539595, 7.73511170298675, 
7.68006974050443, 8.07442411510912, 8.27687965909096, 8.76025039592727, 
8.3345638889156, 9.23658956753677, 8.98160722605782, 8.98234210211611, 
9.57066566368204, 8.74444401914267, 8.98719629775988, 9.18169205278566, 
9.98225438314085, 9.56196773059615, 5.47788158053928, 2.58106090926808, 
3.22420704848299, 1.36953555753786, 0.241334267522977), R = c(11.6679680423377, 
11.0166459173372, 11.1851268491296, 10.7404563561694, 12.1054055597684, 
10.9551321815546, 11.1975918244469, 10.7242192465965, 10.1661703705992, 
11.4840412725324, 11.1248456370953, 11.2529612597628, 10.7694642397996, 
12.3300887767583, 12.0478558531771, 12.3212362249214, 11.5650773932264, 
9.56070414783612, 9.61762902218185, 10.2076240621201, 11.8234628013552, 
10.9184029778985)), .Names = c("ID", "Y", "P", "A", "TA", "TS", 
"R"), na.action = structure(77:78, .Names = c("77", "78"), class = "omit"), row.names = c(NA, 
22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to run a RandomForest on this data set with a leave one ID out cross validation. Thus, I do not want the cross validation to be kind of random. For every run, I would like to leave out the data with the same ID value as the data with the same ID are not independent. This means that data with identical ID will have the same Cross-Validation Index. For instance, the first run will be trained on the data with ID=5,6,8,9 and will be tested on the data with ID=4, the second run will be trained on the data with ID=4,6,8,9 and will be tested on the data with ID=5, and so on. Does someone know how to implement it in R? Below is the command lines I have tried but not sure if it is conceptually correct.

```
# Create Training dataset
df<-na.omit(df)
tvec<-unique(df$ID)
nruns <- length(tvec)
crossclass<-sample(nruns,length(tvec),TRUE)
nobs<-nrow(df)
crossPredict<-rep(NA,nobs)

#Run a RandomForest with leave one out ID CV
for (i in 1:nruns) {
  indtrain<-which(df$ID %in% tvec[!crossclass==i])
  indvalidate<-setdiff(1:nobs,indtrain)
  rf<-randomForest(formula = Y ~ P + TA + TS + R + A, data=df, subset=indtrain,ntree=10000)
  crossPredict[indvalidate]<-predict(rf,df[indvalidate,])
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109340/leave-one-subject-out-cross-validation-in-caret

Comment: It did not seem to work in my case though. I have edited my question with some command lines I have been doing but without using a leave one ID out cross validation. Maybe this will help.

Comment: @SimonB Maybe this post is related? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137000/correlated-cases-and-cross-validation

Comment: @SimonB The `grouping` parameter mentioned in the Cross Validated post is an argument to `cvTools::cvFit`. I presume your `ID` might be used as grouping parameter there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is this:

There need to be as many cross-validation runs as different IDs in the training set. So we collect these IDs in the vector `uniqueIDs`, and then associate each training observation with the correct run in the vector `crossclass`. Like this:

```
uniqueIDs <- unique(train$ID)           
nruns <- length(uniqueIDs)    # number of cross validation runs: one for each unique ID           
crossclass <- match(train$ID, uniqueIDs)
```

The main cross-validation loop your wrote remains the same. (I only added some debug output.)

```
nobs <- nrow(na.omit(train))
crossPredict <- rep(NA, nobs)

for (i in 1:nruns) {
  indtrain <- which(crossclass != i)
  indvalidate <- setdiff(1:nobs, indtrain)
  cat("Run", i, ": training only on observations with ID not", uniqueIDs[i], "\n")
  cat("       IDs in training set:", train[indtrain,"ID"], "\n")
  cat("       IDs in validation set:", train[indvalidate,"ID"], "\n")

  rf_df_CV <- randomForest(Y ~ ., data = train[indtrain,],
                           ntree = 1000, importance = T, na.action = "na.omit")

  crossPredict[indvalidate] <- predict(rf_df_CV, train[indvalidate,])
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
Run 1 : training only on observations with ID not 4 
       IDs in training set: 5 8 6 6 5 5 8 6 
       IDs in validation set: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
Run 2 : training only on observations with ID not 5 
       IDs in training set: 4 4 8 4 6 6 4 4 4 4 8 6 
       IDs in validation set: 5 5 5 
Run 3 : training only on observations with ID not 8 
       IDs in training set: 4 4 5 4 6 6 5 5 4 4 4 4 6 
       IDs in validation set: 8 8 
Run 4 : training only on observations with ID not 6 
       IDs in training set: 4 4 5 8 4 5 5 4 4 4 4 8 
       IDs in validation set: 6 6 6
```

Note that in this example in the random split of `df` into training and test sets, the training set happened to not have any observations with ID = 9. So there is also no CV run with this ID...

Comment: @ WhiteViking.Thanks. How do you define the train object then? It has to be adapted too, right?

Comment: @ WhiteViking. I have edited my question (see the last command line paragraph) based on your answer but not sure if it is conceptually right. What do you think?

Comment: @SimonB I took your question as a simple little R task, but if this is really a conceptual question about how to do CV on correlated data, then I am probably overreaching. I think I better delete this answer. I hope someone else steps in to shed some light.

Comment: I think conceptually your answer is correct and I was also asking for an R task. My first comment was about the `train` object. In your answer does this object is the same as the input `df` or is it defined differently?

Comment: @SimonB In my answer I followed your original setup. (1) Split all data `df` fully at random into a training set and a test set (e.g. a 70/30 split); completely ignore `ID` at this point. (2) Use the training data (those 70%) with cross validation to select the best model among different possible models. For example, we can use CV to select the tree depth that yields the best CV result among a number of possible tree depths. Pick the model that comes out best from the CV runs, it is our *final* model. (3) Assess this model's performance on the test set to estimate eventual prediction error.

Comment: @SimonB So the test set is only used to estimate the final generalisation error. We cannot use it to go back and select a different model again. (But again, I'm not an expert here.)